# Password should contain at least 1 digit - Regex in ValidateJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using ValidateJS library for this. Here is the regex that I'm using but it does accept password without digits as well.

My password should be with length 6 to 16 characters, at least one digit in it.

I want it to able to accept passwords only like:

```
mypass1
1mypass
my1pass
```

where I have atleast 1 number in it.

```
        password: {
          presence: true,
          length: {
            minimum: 6,
            maximum: 16
          },
          format: {
            pattern: "^.*(?=.{6,16})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%]+$",
            message: "should contain at least one number"
          }
        },
```

Comment: Works for me, but you should remove `.*` at the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In password validation, lookaheads are great, see this pattern: `(?=.{6,16})(?=.*\d).+`

It uses two pisitive lookaheads:

`(?=.{6,16})` - assures, that we have at least 6 and at most 16 characters

`(?=.*\d).+` - assures that we have at least one digits

Further details:

`.{6, 16}` - matches between 6 and 16 of any characters

`.*` - matches zero or more of any characters

`\d` - match a digit

`.+` - matches one or more of any characters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCCXAn/1)

Comment: Thanks, I used only (?=.*\d).+ and it worked! Cause I have 6,16 in length already!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this pattern

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this and it will work for you

```
 format: {
   pattern: "^(?=.{6,16})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$",
   message: "should contain at least one number"
 }
```